# Position item at the bottom of the container with css

Tags: html, css

What I'm trying to do is be able to position bottom h1 at the bottom of the h2 box it's in. I used the bottom: 0; but it is going to the bottom of the screen instead of the h2 box I'm trying to position it in. Asking because I've looked for a bit on how to do this and all I can see is people using the bottom:0;

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

body {
  height: 1000px;
}

header {
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  top: 0;
  position: sticky;
  background-color: white;
  height: 8vh;
}

nav {
  min-height: 10vh;
  margin: auto;
  width: 90%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

nav h1,
nav ul {
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  flex: 1;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 10px;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 10px;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

main section h2 {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}

main section section h1 {
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}

.home {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, darkcyan, cyan);
}

.project {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(219, 0, 0), rgb(238, 0, 0))
}

.contact {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, goldenrod, gold);
}

.bottomer {
  background-color: rgb(87, 87, 87);
  height: 10vh;
  padding: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.middleText {
  font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<header>
  <nav>
    <h1>
      Practice
    </h1>
    <ul>
      <li> <a data-page="home" href="#">Foo</a></li>
      <li> <a data-page="project" href="#">Foo</a></li>
      <li> <a data-page="contact" href="#">Foo</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>

<main>
  <section data-index="0" class="home">
    <section>
      <h1 class="bottomer">
        Bottom
      </h1>
    </section>
    <h2 class="middleText">Fooer</h2>
  </section>
  <section data-index="1" class="project">
    <h2 class="middleText">even more foo</h2>
  </section>
  <section data-index="2" class="contact">
    <h2 class="middleText">fooiest</h2>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: Your `<h1>` element should - visually - follow the `<section data-index="2">` element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely positioned element are position with respect to their nearest positioned ancestor. So to make it work the way you want, add `position: relative;` to the home class:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

body {
  height: 1000px;
}

header {
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  top: 0;
  position: sticky;
  background-color: white;
  height: 8vh;
}

nav {
  min-height: 10vh;
  margin: auto;
  width: 90%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

nav h1,
nav ul {
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  flex: 1;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 10px;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 10px;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

main section h2 {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
}

main section section h1 {
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}

.home {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, darkcyan, cyan);
  position:relative;
}

.project {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(219, 0, 0), rgb(238, 0, 0))
}

.contact {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, goldenrod, gold);
}

.bottomer {
  background-color: rgb(87, 87, 87);
  height: 10vh;
  padding: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.middleText {
  font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<header>
  <nav>
    <h1>
      Practice
    </h1>
    <ul>
      <li> <a data-page="home" href="#">Foo</a></li>
      <li> <a data-page="project" href="#">Foo</a></li>
      <li> <a data-page="contact" href="#">Foo</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>

<main>
  <section data-index="0" class="home">
    <section>
      <h1 class="bottomer">
        Bottom
      </h1>
    </section>
    <h2 class="middleText">Fooer</h2>
  </section>
  <section data-index="1" class="project">
    <h2 class="middleText">even more foo</h2>
  </section>
  <section data-index="2" class="contact">
    <h2 class="middleText">fooiest</h2>
  </section>
</main>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do bottom:0 when h2 was in the container of h1 and then you specify h2 to be at the bottom of the container. I recommend you to study bootstrap classes, you will get comprehensive ides of styling and positioning.

Here, according to my understanding, you should put h2 in h1 like in the container then specify bottom/top whatever with respect of the container element.

```html
<div class="coantiner-fluid">
  <div class="header01">
    <div class="haeder02">
      //Your Code
```